# Using the Mobile SDK for the Mavic 2 what language needs to be used for the iOS app?

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm looking into the Mavic 2 Pro for autonomous flight. I just need to get some more information on what language I should use, and which SDK is the best: Mobile, Ux, Onboard, or the Windows SDK.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do not ask for opinions. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

autonomous flight is a wide topic.

based on gps or gpsless there could be a huge difference.

when dealing with normal

## MSDK

normal Java should be sufficient.

But when you dealing with research level vision-based navigation .e.g. [SVO](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo), then bottom layer has to be C++ and you need a corss compiler for it.

[image]

DJI

## wsdk

also can give what you want. Below is the demo that I did use DJI WSDK alpha release and Windows UWP. As for what language it is, I think it is C#. but not sure(uwp not traditional C# anymore), I coded it without knowing what language it is. Just follow the sample style and API. You can code without knowing what language

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcndnHkriyA&t=12s

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, and as far as the autonomous flight goes, it will be gpsless. Do you know if the smart controller is worth the extra money or if we are better off just using the standard controller?

Comment: Haven't played with uxsdk4.1 yet. I would suggest you to value your life, keep away from fresh dji sdk yet for at least half year. Pretty sure plenty of bug and malfunction.  always keep it in mind that, DJI release means it is beta. DJI  beta relase means it is alpha. DJI alpha is OMG/WTF is it.